# expected vs expected to be

Tags: grammar

I discussed this with IMS team in my last meeting and the current backlog **is expected to** reduce substantially in the coming weeks..

should this sentence be rephrased as following and which one is more apt.

1.I discussed this with IMS team in my last meeting and the current backlog is expected to be reduced substantially in the coming weeks..

2.I discussed this with IMS team in my last meeting and the current backlog is expected to get reduced substantially in the coming weeks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence with "*is expected to reduce*" is fine own it's own.
But if the changes are necessary to be made, **be reduced** would be more correct.

Reference: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/be+reduced

Comment: What about *get reduced*?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It is right, but I think be is more preferred.

Comment: I somewhere read that 'get ' is only used with action verbs but not state verbs.. Is 'reduce' an action verb here?